# PouchDB: Multiple documents with attachments

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I need to fetch several documents from my db, each one has an attachment, how can I get every document and assign its attachment dynamically and display a list using AngularJS?

Here's the bit of code I'm using:

```
db.getAttachment(doc._id,"image.png").then(function (blob){
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    $scope.image = url;
  });
```

How can "image.png" be a dynamic id? So I can iterate on it with a for loop

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the _attachments field and do something like:

```
for(var key in doc._attachments){
  db.getAttachment(doc._id,key).then(function (blob){
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    $scope.image = url;
  });
}
```